# Devexpress MVC object as callback argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I try to make some abstract class for all my grid view controllers. Since all controllers will have the same GridViewPartial Action but with different parameters I decided to create struct ActionParams with Args property to keep all input parameters there.
So here is my struct:

```
   public struct ActionParams
        {
            public Dictionary<string, object> Args { get; set; }

        }
```

And controller action

```
public ActionResult GridViewPartial(ActionParams input) {  }
```

The problem is in JS onBeginCallback function. I tried to perform this task in 2 ways:

1)

```
 function onBeginCallback(s, e)
 {
                     e.customArgs["Args"]={"value1":1,"value2":2};
 }
```

Instead of getting string key and int value, I got string key and string[] value. As I understand this is serialization problem.

2)

```
 function onBeginCallback(s, e)
    {
        var editorsNames = {"value1":1 ),"value2":2}
        e.customArgs["Args"] = $.toJSON(editorsNames);
    }
```

In this way I got empty Args. But object is in Request.Params so I got in following way:

```
 public ActionResult GridViewPartial(ActionParams input)
        {

            string jsonText = Request.Params["Args"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonText))
            { }
            else
            {
                ActionParams data = new ActionParams>();
                try
                {
                    data.Args = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string,int>>(jsonText);
                }
                catch
                {
                    ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = "Incorrect data";
                }
            }

        }
```

**Now I'm wondering if is possible to send this JSON object directly to input.Args like it was in case 1?** ( for simple jquery ajax everything works fine).

Hope someone with great devexpress MVC control expressions will give me some good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [How to pass complex types to the server with a callback customArgs argument](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q328654):

> When you create an object and pass it to the `e.customArgs` argument,
>   our code does not serialize the object to a string, and thus you do
>   not get the client-side object on the server side correctly.

The first effort to reveal how raw JSON object passed to controller by using `console.log(e.customArgs)` shows this object structure in console:

```
Object { Args: Object {"value1": 1, "value2": 2}}
```

When the input `Args` parameter assigned as `Dictionary<String, int>`, seems I was able to capture both keys and values in JSON object by this code:

```
public ActionResult GridViewPartial(Dictionary<String, int> Args)
{
    // Args parameter contains 2 arrays with Count = 2
    // Args.Keys contains "value1" and "value2"
    // Args.Values contains 1 and 2
    foreach (String key in Args.Keys)
    {
        // do something to pass keys
    }

    foreach (int value in Args.Values)
    {
        // do something to pass values
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Variable: Args
Count: 2
Content:
0x0000 {["value1", 1]}
0x0001 {["value2", 2]}
```

However, when I changed the value part to `Dictionary<String, Object>`, I found same thing as your problem: the `Value` part changed to `System.String[]` array which contains number 1 or 2 as string.

```
Variable: Args
Count: 2
Content:
0x0000 {["value1", System.String[]]} => Value: String[1] => 0x0000 = "1"
0x0001 {["value2", System.String[]]} => Value: String[1] => 0x0000 = "2"
```

Attempt to change input variable type into `Dictionary<String, String>` returns this:

```
Variable: Args
Count: 2
Content:
0x0000 {["value1", "1"]}
0x0001 {["value2", "2"]}
```

The second case uses [jQuery JSON plugin](https://github.com/Krinkle/jquery-json) which converts the object given by `editorsNames` to JSON-formatted string, then passed to response as a plain string which recognizable by deserializer on controller side. This approach fulfills how client-side objects should be passed to:

> 1. A custom object should be serialized to a string;
> 2. This string will be obtained on the server side using the `Request.Params` collection. If you deserialize the string, you will be
>      able to create your custom object on the server side.

Hence, I concluded that you can pass raw JSON object by 2 ways:

1. By using `customArgs` directly, you can declare a `Dictionary` as input parameter and passing values using numeric value type or `String`. Avoid using `Object` type which seems creating array of string as value part.
2. By using `Request.Params`, convert JSON object to encoded string and pass it into `customArgs`, then use deserialization to reveal key and values.

NB: Instead of using a struct contains Dictionary as single input parameter, you can write several `GridViewPartial` method overloads with different amount of input parameters to handle grid partial view.

Any suggestions or erratas welcome.

Additional reference:

[How to pass complex objects to a callback Action as callback arguments](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3338)

Comment: I didn't try <string,int> at all) After reading your answer I decided to make <string,string> that allow me to send ANY data that I want and that on convert it in the server into data that I need.
Now I am getting my json in the dictionary where key= objname amd value = serialized string)

Comment: Thx, for your detail problem analyze and suggestions